# What are some quick ways of making N copies of a particular file?

Tags: files, cp

Say, if I wanted to make `N` copies of `a.txt`, and wanted them to be numbered `a1.txt`, `a2.txt`, `a3.txt`, etc...

How would I do such a thing succinctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cp` itself can only make one copy (of a single file) at a time, but it's not too difficult with a quick loop:

```
for i in {1..10}; do cp a.txt a$i.txt; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have your N value in a bash variable:

```
for i in `seq 1 $N`; do cp a.txt a$i.txt; done
```

or

```
for ((i=1;i<=$N;i++)); do cp a.txt a$i.txt; done
```

or with the loop shown in Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions using `cp` are somewhat inefficient, because you don't need to read the same file `N` times to make `N` copies. One can use `tee` instead:

```
cat a.txt | ( for i in `seq 1 $N`; do echo a"$i".txt; done | xargs tee )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more funky, you can for example do:
`for t in $(seq --format="funky-%03.0f-numbered.txt" 25 3 40); do cp orig $t; done`.